# Is it ok to link to LilyPond GitHub Repositories?

Tags: discussion

On other SE sites like `code review` some people linked to their [GitHub](https://github.com/) repositories to give readers the chance to have look to the code as a whole and not just the snippets used in the question, as well as to track improvements or the use of answers within a whole real live context.

This question is gaining towards [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) where the questions really are about `code` and `coding`.

Here are two examples where I used this within a question:
[example one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92506/lilypond-change-tuplet-bracket-to-a-small-bow)
[example two](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92304/music-engraving-note-with-two-accidentals-natural-and-sharp-%e2%99%af)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems absolutely fine to provide more context to a question. Particularly with questions of *coding* in systems like LilyPond or ABC, providing the full piece through a link makes it easier to focus on the relevant portions.

I think for this site, this is preferable to creating a Minimal Compilable Example which is typical on other sites.

Comment: I’d still say an MCE is preferable.

Comment: @Dave MCE = Minimial compileable example? like MWE = Minimal working example